# Vuetify v-checkbox hide-details and text on the same line

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to obtain a simple `v-checkbox` and a text just nearby (not the Label) **on the same line just near the checkbox**. My code is as simple as:

```html
<v-container fluid>
  <v-row>
    <v-col>
      <v-checkbox>
      </v-checkbox>
      Some text
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

and can be found at : https://codepen.io/SomeUserName678905/pen/GRqaVYL

My versions:

- `Vuetify v2.3.x`
- `Vue v2.x`

I've tried to play with the various [Vuetify Flex class helpers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/#flex-direction) witout any success this far.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE After @tony19 answer**

```html
<v-container fluid>
  <v-row align="center">
    <v-checkbox hide-details></v-checkbox>
    Some text
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

successfully makes *text and checkbox* on the same line, **but** as soon as I set the `hide-details` property on `v-checkbox`, text and checkbox are no longer aligned.

I've created this [new codepen](https://codepen.io/SomeUserName678905/pen/GRqbKjR) to illustrate the new problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `v-checkbox` and text in the same `v-row`, and use `align="center"` to vertically align them on the line:

```html
<v-row align="center">
  <v-checkbox></v-checkbox>
  Some text
</v-row>
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OJXeLPP)

If using `v-checkbox.hideDetails`, the component's margins are adjusted, which offsets the alignment in `align="center"`, but you could workaround that with `align="end"`:

```html
<v-row align="end">
  <v-checkbox hide-details></v-checkbox>
  Some text
</v-row>
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/XWKLroy)

Alternatively, you could use `v-simple-checkbox`, which doesn't have the margin adjustment:

```html
<v-row align="center">
  <v-simple-checkbox></v-simple-checkbox>
  Some text
</v-row>
```

[demo 3](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OJXeLZR)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you avoiding the checkbox's label?

Comment: I'm trying to learn `Vuetify` by trying to replicate [this vuetify based TODO manager](https://github.com/davidgaroro/vuetify-todo-pwa/blob/master/src/components/TodoItem.vue) and _text_ should be the _title of the todo_ , _selectable_, etc... . I don't think *checkbox labels* are well suited for this kind of long text, but I may be wrong///

Comment: You could use a `v-simple-checkbox` instead, which also resolves the issue: https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OJXeLZR

Comment: Thanks again ! This is exactly what I wanted !
However, I don't understand why the `v-simple-checkbox` solves my problem here. Any idea what was the problem introduced with the `v-checkbox` `hide-details` property ?